# How to create a Sequelize cli db migration after changes to the model

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I am starting with sequelize and was following their [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wHTBxtk8ezo) online. After running

```
node_modules/.bin/sequelize model:create --name User --attributes username:string

node_modules/.bin/sequelize model:create --name Task --attributes title:string
```

which created the migration files for create user and create task. Then I had to add  the associations to each model as follow:

```
// user.js
classMethods: {
  associate: function(models) {
    User.hasMany(models.Task);
  }
}

// task.js
classMethods: {
  associate: function(models) {
    Task.belongsTo(models.User);
  }
}
```

However, the migration files  for creating the tables for user and task are already created. Do i have to manually update them to add the relationships? "migration:create" command creates the migration skeleton file. Do I manually fill out the skeleton files or is there a way to automatically create the complete migration file besides model creation?

P.S i have seen the following stackoverflow question:  [How to auto generate migrations with Sequelize CLI from Sequelize models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835801/how-to-auto-generate-migrations-with-sequelize-cli-from-sequelize-models)

Answer (score 11):

You can create a separate migration from an empty migration file. I did that when I needed to add a few extra columns to a table.

```
sequelize migration:create --name users
```

Then in my new migration file.

```
module.exports = {
  up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    queryInterface.addColumn(
      'Users',
      'url',
      Sequelize.STRING
    );
  },

  down: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    queryInterface.removeColumn(
      'Users',
      'url',
      Sequelize.STRING
    );
  }
};
```

Then just run the migrations.

```
sequelize db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this new npm package

```
Sequelize-mig
```

Install:

```
npm install sequelize-mig -g / yarn global add sequelize-mig
```

then use it like this

```
sequelize-mig migration:make -n <migration name>
```

and it will auto generate the migration file for you with all updates