# Sequelize CLI generate migration files for updated models?

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I'm wanting to generate migration files for `/models/model_name.js` (model) files. Although I haven't found a way todo this yet.

So say I created a model `articles` with just an `id` field, and then I edited that `models/articles.js`file, how can I use the sequelize cli to generate a migration file, so I can then update my database structure?!

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to auto-generate Sequelize.js model migrations. See this question and its answers also: [How to auto generate migrations with Sequelize CLI from Sequelize models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835801/how-to-auto-generate-migrations-with-sequelize-cli-from-sequelize-models).

Answer (score 0):

Install this npm:

```
Sequelize-mig
```

pretty updated and new

Install it with:

```
npm install sequelize-mig -g / yarn global add sequelize-mig
```

You can use it like this

```
sequelize-mig migration:make -n <migration name>
```

and it will generate the migration file by reading your changes and comparing them