# NodeJS application database versioning and data migration

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am planning to use Postgres as my database and sequelize as my ORM framework one of my NodeJS project. I need your suggestion on how to accomplish database table changes in production enviroment.

For example , we deployed our version-1 application with some database schema.
Later , there is a change in my schema in Version-2. Say one of the table is altered and few columns are dropped and few columns are added.
Also one of the table itself is not required in Version-2.

In my production , I have some database with data. When I install Version-2 of my NodeJS application , I need to keep the old data as it is and apply the new database schema of Version-2.

How to achieve this , Let me point out some reference to this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sequelize (or rather, sequelize-cli) has [built in support for migrations](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/migrations.html).

You can write migrations using the Sequelize js api (e.g. `queryInterface.dropColumn('users', 'address')`) or write raw SQL and pass it to `sequelize.query()`

Comment: Do I need to write my own script file to handle this case . "Sequelize" won't  do it automatically?

Comment: If you have `sequelize-cli` installed you can have it generate migration skeletons for you (run `sequelize db:migration:create`) which you then modify to make the required database changes - is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes I want a kind of solution which auto generate migration script using the sequelize data model. Can you point me some reference page or suggest some solution?

Comment: I see what you mean now. I would also like to generate migrations from model definitions, but unfortunately it's not possible! Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835801/how-to-auto-generate-migrations-with-sequelize-cli-from-sequelize-models for some workarounds and advice