# Should Sequelize migrations update model files?

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

Are Sequelize migrations supposed to keep your model files in line with your database?

I used the sequelize cli to bootstrap a simple project and create a model `node_modules/.bin/sequelize model:generate --name User --attributes email:string`. I migrated this with no issue.

Then I created the following migration file to add a notNull constraint to the user email attribute.

**updateEmail migration**

```
const models = require("../models")

module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
      return queryInterface.changeColumn(models.User.tableName, 'email',{
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      });
    },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
      return queryInterface.changeColumn(models.User.tableName, 'email',{
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      });
    },
};
```

The database schema updated to add the constraint but the model file did not.  Is there a way to automatically update the model files as you make migrations?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Is there a way to automatically update the model files as you
>   make migrations?

Unfortunately, no. There is no level of synchronization between sequelize models and migration except for their initial creation from `sequelize model:create`. However, the workflow suggested in this question is that updates should propagate *from* migrations *to* models. This confuses me slightly, as typically the migrations are to be auto-generated from changes to the models, not necessarily vice-versa.

There have been on-going open issues tracking these features that you may find helpful to subscribe to:

- [Generate initial migration from model?](https://github.com/sequelize/cli/issues/157)
- [Auto-Create Migrations](https://github.com/sequelize/cli/issues/257)
- [Possible to generate migrations to update existing models?](https://github.com/sequelize/cli/issues/388)

**Community Suggestions/Solutions:**

Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/28431648/8954866
As suggested, a workaround is to re-create models using `sequelize-cli` when introducing simple changes. However, there are clear limitations to this methodology as many configurations are not possible to define from the cli such as associations.

Additionally, an npm package [sequelize-auto-migrations](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-auto-migrations) does exist that does provide support for generating migrations, however it doesn't seem to be an overly active project.

**Conclusion:**

> Should Sequelize migrations update model files?

`Sequelize`/`sequelize-cli` does not yet support this feature.

*Should an ORMs create tools to auto generate migrations?* 
Yes, this is desired functionality as otherwise the developers are forced to violate principles such as **DRY** and manage the same logic in different files.