# Sequelize primaryKey as UUID in MySql database - not working

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js, uuid

I'm facing the problem with implementation model in Sequalize with primary key as uuid. I follow step by step all instruction, but still I cannot solve it.

This is how my model looks like:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var Todo = sequelize.define('Todo', {
    title: DataTypes.STRING,
    description: DataTypes.STRING,
    test: DataTypes.UUID
  }, {});
  Todo.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
  };
  return Todo;
};
```

And migration file:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Todos', {
      id: {
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV1
      },
      title: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      description: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      test: {
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Todos');
  }
};
```

After calling post method to create element, I habe got an empty value in ID column, and NULL in test column...

The Datebase is MySql.

Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 14):

**1) Setting Custom Keys in Sequelize**

> I'm facing the problem with implementation model in Sequalize with
>   primary key as uuid.

By default, if your model *does not* contain a key with `primaryKey: true`, then `sequelize` assumes a PK of type `INTEGER` named `id`.

In your case, it seems like you wish to make your own custom PK.

Use the following *in your model*:

```
var Todo = sequelize.define('Todo', {
    id: {
      primaryKey: true,
      type: DataTypes.UUID
    }
    // rest of properties
 });
```

**2) Validations**

> After calling post method to create element, I habe got an empty value in ID column, and NULL in test column...

Without much information regarding not only your query, but how you seeded the database, it's hard to answer specifically.

However, it doesn't surprise me that `test` column was `null`, because you have not listed any validations. Thus if you seed/create rows that do not set a `test` value, it will be `null`.

To create validations do the following

model:

```
var Todo = sequelize.define('Todo', {
    // rest of properties
    test: {
      allowNull: false
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      validate: {
        notNull: true
      }
    }
});
```

migration:

```
queryInterface.createTable('Todos', {
    // rest of properties
    test: {
      allowNull: false,
      type: Sequelize.UUID,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4
    }
});
```

**3) Keeping Models and Migrations Synchronized**

(see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49796801/8954866) In `sequelize`, models and migrations are not automatically in-sync with one another, except when initially generated using `sequelize-cli model:generate`. I'm unsure if you ran your migrations or if you were running your query in a unit test against the model. But you have to make sure they are synchronized. A primary example is that in the above case, your migration says `id` is of type `UUID`, but your model will think it's of type `INTEGER`.

**References**

- [Setting Custom Primary Keys](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/advanced/legacy.html#primary-keys)
- [Validations and allowNull](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html#validations)

Comment: I have this in my code. The problem with this is that it doesn't translate to an ID column with a default value for UUID in the database. By default, it leaves it at null if I insert a row directly (using a database client). Sequelize should set a default value at the dabase level, in case a user is not using the API.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your package.json has updated uuid module, this was the problem in my case.

```
accessSecret: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    },
```

This works fine,
just make sure package.json has

```
"uuid": "^8.2.0",
```

Comment: why though? i thought MySQL itself has UUID type

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this issue is the same for both MySQL and Postgres: Sequelize needs to use the `defaultValue` setting of the model to point to its `uuid` dependency.

For example, for an entity called Product, create your migration like this:

```
"use strict";
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.createTable("Products", {
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        primaryKey: true,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
      },
      productName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
      },
    });
  },
  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.dropTable("Products");
  },
};
```

Then, create your model like this:

```
"use strict";
const { Model } = require("sequelize");
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Product extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      // associations
    }
  }
  Product.init(
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        primaryKey: true,
      },
      productName: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: "Product",
    }
  );
  return Product;
};
```

Note that in your model, you're defining `defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4`.

When you create a new instance of Product, you only need the `name` field. The UUID is auto-generated by the Sequelize model.

```
const {
    Product
  } = require("./models");

const createProduct = async (name) => {
  const newProductData = { productName: "First product" };
  const creationResult = await Product.create(newProductData);
};
```

The id field in the model will trace the defaultValue setting back to the `v4()` function of the [uuid package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) that Sequelize relies on to auto-generate the UUID as part of the model operation, not as part of native Postgres.