# Why doesn't sequelize-cli include the ID in the model file?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

When I run the following command:

```
sequelize-cli model:create --name User --attributes "dispName:string,email:string,phoneNum1:string"
```

I end up with the following migration file:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('Users', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      dispName: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      phoneNum1: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('Users');
  }
};
```

and the following model file:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    dispName: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    phoneNum1: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {});
  User.associate = function(models) {
    // associations can be defined here
  };
  return User;
};
```

Questions:

1. Why doesn't the model file contain the definition for `id`?
2. If I change the name and/or definition of the primary key field (the key will be generated externally and will be set on an object before it is saved), then do I have to include the definition of the ID field in the model file? Why/why not?

Versions:

```
[Node: 12.14.1, CLI: 5.5.1, ORM: 5.21.3]
```

The following do not answer my question:

- [Should Sequelize migrations update model files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49161055/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't declare PK in your model sequelize assumes you have the **id** PK. This is by design. And yes you can rename your PK in the model. Just don't forget to setup PK in the mode properly according to a real PK in your DB.