# How to automatically create migration files when using sequelize?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

Is it possible to automatically create migration files when using sequelize?

For example if I change my model, is there a way to automatically create a migration file that reflects those changes and run the migration to effect those changes in the database. Or do I have to manually create migration files myself?

I am using PostgreSQL.

Comment: just seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835801/how-to-auto-generate-migrations-with-sequelize-cli-from-sequelize-models

Answer (score 1):

There is a package for that

```
Sequelize-mig
```

its maintained and documented.

Install it with:

```
npm install sequelize-mig -g / yarn global add sequelize-mig
```

then use it like this

```
sequelize-mig migration:make -n <migration name>
```

and it will generate the migration file

Comment: sequelize v. 4 support only, last commit at 2020

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend Sequelize-mig, as referenced by MRVMV. I have 25 years of experience in creating my own ORM, and for my most recent project I decided to finally use an existing ORM. I chose Sequelize and as I got going with it, I was sorely disappointed that it does not have the ability to automatically genereate migration files by inspecting model files. This issue landed me here in this SO thread, and so I tried sequelize-mig. I read the docs and tried it out for about 4 hours and I find it to be working very well.

Using it, you can just create/modify your models .js files, then call "npx sequelize-mig migration:make --preview" to see what it will do. Carefully inspect all the preview code and make changes until you love the result. Then call "npx sequelize-mig migration:make -n <>" and it will populate the migration files. Carefully inspect those and when you love them, then use sequelize to migrate to your dev database by calling "npx sequelize-cli db:migrate" and that's it.

Next up, I will decide upon the best way for moving these migrations to production. But that decision doesn't have anything to do with sequelize-mig - it is the same decision you have to make for sequelize itself, just that now you get automatic generation of your migration files, thanks to sequelize-mig.

Highly recommend sequelize-mig!