# Create migration files from existing models in sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have pre-defined models in my project. I want to create migration files using those models using sequelize in Typescript-Node. Is there a way to do it?
Can I get the steps to do it?

Comment: Duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835801/how-to-auto-generate-migrations-with-sequelize-cli-from-sequelize-models

Comment: @kunal, do you already have sequelize models created?

Comment: @Pram Yes. I already have the models which Im using for DB calls. I want to remove sequelize.sync and use migration

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [sequelize-typescript-migration-lts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-typescript-migration-lts/v/3.1.5)
 npm package, might be helpful for you.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32347174)