# How to automatically add a column to a Sequelize table?

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I've generated a model using `node_modules/.bin/sequelize model:create --name Student --attributes firstName:string,email:string`. Now I want to add a new column, `major`.  I know you can manually create a migration like so:

```
module.exports = {
  up: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    // logic for transforming into the new state
    return queryInterface.addColumn(
      'major',
      'compSci',
     Sequelize.BOOLEAN
    );

  },

  down: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    // logic for reverting the changes
    return queryInterface.removeColumn(
      'major',
      'compSci'
    );
  }
}
```

Is it possible to edit the model, and have migrations be automatically created? So in student.js you'd add `{major:{type:Sequelize.STRING}}`, and then generate new migrations?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Sequelize cannot auto-generate migrations [source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27835801/4180797). I'll try TypeORM instead, whose github page says that it has automatic migrations.