# How to generate migrations automatically from Sequelize models

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli, automatic-migration

I just started to program with node.js. I needed an ORM so I used Sequelize library. I wrote my User model as follows and I need to create a migration for it. Is there any way to create migrations automatically from the Sequelize models instead of writing them on my own?
I tried package `sequelize-auto-migrations` and run `npx makemigration --name create_users` but it returns error:

```
Unexpected token {
```

I'm using ***node v10.19.3***

This is my Sequelize model:

```js
const Model = require('sequelize');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User extends Model {
    getFullname() {
      return [ this.firstname, this.lastname ].join(' ');
    }
  }
  User.init({
    firstName: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
    lastName: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
    email: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false, unique: true },
    national_number: { type: DataTypes.STRING, unique: true },
    phone_number: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false, unique: true },
    username: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false, unique: true },
    join_date: { type: DataTypes.DATEONLY, defaultValue: sequelize.NOW },
    last_login: { type: DataTypes.DATE },
    password: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
    active: { type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN, allowNull: false, defaultValue: true }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'User',
  });
  return User;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try sequelize-cli instead. To run migrations you have to run this command `npx sequelize-cli model:generate`
This link on sequelize.com should help https://sequelize.org/master/manual/migrations.html

Comment: I have seen that URL but that is for running migrations not creating. I need to create them automatically. Now I have to create them manually every time I make changes to my models

Comment: in the link it says you can create migrations using this sequelize-cli model:generate --name

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835801/how-to-auto-generate-migrations-with-sequelize-cli-from-sequelize-models

this link will help you.

Comment: there is no way to automatically generate initial migrations from existing models in sequelize-cli. Looks like author of the answer not even checked info he suggests to use