# Error trying to use sequelize to create migrations

Tags: javascript, database, model, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I'm using the sequelize in my project to modelling my database for a API REST,but when a try to create a migration for my db, the sequelize only shows me the options for the execution,event though I already using the right commands to create the migration. Sequelize,sequelize-cli are already installed,I'm using mariadb. I already tested change the equal sign for a space between the "create" and "alunos", tried double quotes and single quotes on create and alunos too.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to auto generate migrations with Sequelize CLI from Sequelize models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835801/how-to-auto-generate-migrations-with-sequelize-cli-from-sequelize-models)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835801/

Comment: I tried, but it didn't worked

Comment: `sequelize model:create --name MyUser --attributes first_name:string,last_name:string,bio:text`

Comment: with sequelize, we cannot generate model from database.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for generating migrations is

npx sequelize-cli migration:generate --name *NameOfMigration*