# Trying to generate a migration after generating the models using sequelize-auto

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-auto

I have run this command to generate the models from my MySQL:

node node_modules/sequelize-auto/bin/sequelize-auto -h localhost -d coasteye_new -u root -x PASSWORD --dialect mysql -o models

So the models are now stored in the "node_project/models" directory. For example this one:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('user', {
    id: {
      autoIncrement: true,
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
      allowNull: true,
      unique: "name"
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
      allowNull: false
    },
    id_role: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    },
    role: {
      type: DataTypes.ENUM('root','twm staff','client'),
      allowNull: false
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(70),
      allowNull: false,
      unique: "unique_email"
    },
    fullname: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
      allowNull: true
    },
    activated: {
      type: DataTypes.TINYINT,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 1
    },
    token: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
      allowNull: false
    },
    phone: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(70),
      allowNull: false
    },
    api_token: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(200),
      allowNull: true
    },
    api_token_valid_until: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: true
    },
    has_stations_in_the_new_user_deployment_xref_table: {
      type: DataTypes.TINYINT,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 0
    },
    send_the_status_daily_report_by_email: {
      type: DataTypes.TINYINT,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 0
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    tableName: 'user',
    timestamps: false,
    indexes: [
      {
        name: "PRIMARY",
        unique: true,
        using: "BTREE",
        fields: [
          { name: "id" },
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "unique_email",
        unique: true,
        using: "BTREE",
        fields: [
          { name: "email" },
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "name",
        unique: true,
        using: "BTREE",
        fields: [
          { name: "name" },
        ]
      },
    ]
  });
};
```

After that I have modified the field "phone" by "telephone" this way:

```
phone: {
  type: DataTypes.STRING(70),
  allowNull: false
},
```

to

```
telephone: {
  type: DataTypes.STRING(70),
  allowNull: false
},
```

Then I have run this:

> (env) jgarcia@Javier-PC:/var/www/node_test$ npx sequelize
> migration:generate --name test_migration
>
> Sequelize CLI [Node: 18.3.0, CLI: 6.4.1, ORM: 6.20.1]
>
> migrations folder at "/var/www/node_test/migrations" already exists.
> New migration was created at
> /var/www/node_test/migrations/20220615115322-test_migration.js .

But I get an "empty" migration as you can see here below:

```
(env) jgarcia@Javier-PC:/var/www/node_test$ cat /var/www/node_test/migrations/20220615115322-test_migration.js
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  async up (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    /**
     * Add altering commands here.
     *
     * Example:
     * await queryInterface.createTable('users', { id: Sequelize.INTEGER });
     */
  },

  async down (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    /**
     * Add reverting commands here.
     *
     * Example:
     * await queryInterface.dropTable('users');
     */
  }
};
```

I expected that the file `20220615115322-test_migration.js` contained some reference to my change: from `phone` to `telephone`.

Regards
Javier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the `migration:generate` CLI command does. It doesn't interact with your models at all. [See this SO thread for additional information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835801/how-to-auto-generate-migrations-with-sequelize-cli-from-sequelize-models).

You can pass additional parameters into your `migration:generate` command to get the CLI to write some of the code for you. You can also use [Sequelize Auto-Migrations](https://github.com/Scimonster/sequelize-auto-migrations), but that package has not seen any updates in a long time and probably has compatibility issues with newer versions of Sequelize.

Comment: Looking a little bit closer at your question, I see that you're trying to use sequelize-auto. From what I can tell about that package, all it does it generate models based off of an existing database. The migration:generate command you discussed is a part of the sequelize-cli package.